# Check if a character is equal to \ in C

Tags: c, char

I need to check into a loop if the user inserts '\' for exiting from the menu.

```
while(choise != '\'){
 // do stuff
}
```

But I get this error:

> error: missing terminating ' character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backslashes are special characters and need to be escaped with another backslash:

```
while (choice != '\\') {
```

Answer (score 4):

`\` backslash is an escape character.

> An escape sequence is a sequence of characters that does not represent
>   itself when used inside a character or string literal, but is
>   translated into another character or a sequence of characters that may
>   be difficult or impossible to represent directly [[here]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C).

So you should do:

```
while (choise != '\\'){
  // do stuff
}
```